# Downloading mp3 files in java on Android

Tags: java, android, download

What is the best way to download an mp3 file in java (on Android sdk)?
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/package-summary.html

Should I be using sockets? If so - what kind of "Stream" reader should I use?
I have also read something about "intents" - is this something that is applicable here?

I am also curious as to what should one do if connection gets interrupted - can I resume the download somehow or restart it?

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHat protocol does the server support?

If it's HTTP, you should use HttpURLConnection. If server supports it, you can use the Range header to resume the downloading.

Comment: The server supports HTTP. Basically it's for downloading mp3's from podcasts.